# passing a templated class with constants as an argument

Tags: c++, templates, constants, compile-time-constant

My template class looks like this:

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGTH, typename T = int> class matrix { ... }
```

So plain and simple, the template arguments determine this size of the matrix. The size is logically constant, so I implemented it to be consant. But when I try to write a function that accepts my `matrix`, I run into the following problem:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix &m){ ...}
```

Writen like so, the compiler rightfully objects the lack of template arguments... But

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix<unsigned, unsigned> &m){ ...}
```

triggers this error: `error:   expected a constant of type 'unsigned int', got 'unsigned> int'`

Which is also kind of true, since `matrix` expects constants, not types.

How to deal with this? I'm sure I'm  not the frst to encounter this problem, what's the most "canonical" way to  approach this problem of passing constant-parametrized templates?

Comment: overloaded `operator<<` needs to be template as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option #1

Declare the `operator<<` as a *friend* function in the scope of the `matrix` class:

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGTH, typename T = int>
class matrix
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix& m)
    //                                                      ^^^^^^ plain name
    {
        return os;
    }
};
```

#### Option #2

Make `operator<<` a function template as well:

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGHT, typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix<WIDTH, HEIGHT, T>& m)
//                                                      ^^^^^  ^^^^^^  ^
{
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `operator<<(ostream&)` overload for your template class `matrix` as a template which should be the obvious solution here

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGTH, typename T = int> 
class matrix 
{ 
public:
    T arr[WIDTH][HEIGTH];
};
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGTH, typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix<WIDTH, HEIGTH,T> &m)
{ 
    // formatting inserter of m  onto os
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    matrix<10, 10> m;
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
}
```

But generally speaking, if your `operator<<(ostream&)` needs access to your private data (which generally would), you would end up declaring it as friend. If you do not want to repeat the remplate parameters, place the `operator<<(ostream&)` non-member friend in the scope of your matrix class

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGTH, typename T = int> 
class matrix 
{ 
     T arr[WIDTH][HEIGTH];
     friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix &m)
     { 
         // formatting inserter of m  onto os
         return os;
     }
};
```

Comment: At least you're pretty consistent in spelling HEIGTH wrong :p (up voted)

Comment: @CarloWood: Actually, I copied it from OP and never noticed that its misspelled. In any case I will leave it to be in sync with OPs question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded `operator<<` needs to be template as well:

```
template<unsigned WIDTH, unsigned HEIGHT, typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const matrix<WIDTH, HEIGHT, T> &m){
  // ...
  return os;
}
```